# How to run set and select query in a single statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a group concat statement whose length is beyond 1024 characters. To override the default length of 1024 characters of `group_concat` I have to run the following statement first
`SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;` and then I have to run my select query. But I don't want to run two separate queries.

Is there any way I can combine both the queries and run as a single query?

Comment: Why do you not want to run two separate queries? That would look cleaner.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @programmer-man I'm trying to run the SET query through nodejs but it doesn't seem to work. That's why I'm looking if there's any way I can combine both these queries.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using MySQL server.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql ?

Comment: I'm using sequelize.

Comment: I've not yet had cause to use the GROUP_CONCAT function, so my suspicion is you don't need it either.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the default length in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
group_concat_max_len=1000000
```